# ASP.NET with NHibernate - How can I get the ID of an entity just inserted on postback

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

As per title. Using native ID's

The only thing I can think to do is to call GetByExample(entityJustInserted) and pick the one with the highest ID. Not great...anyone got a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it directly off of the entity you just inserted:

For example:

```
entityRepository.Save(entity);
return entity.Id;
```

NHibernate will automatically populate the property with the generated id.

Comment: Also, `Save` returns the new id too (in case it's private or non-mapped)